# SQL Server Replication: "ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN" is not propagated to subscribers

Tags: sql-server, replication, merge-replication, ddl

We are running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 as publisher & distributor, and SQL Server 2005 SP3 as subscriber. The replication of schema changes is activated, and the replication has been running for years, including frequent schema changes (new column, new constraints, etc).

The following instruction was sent on the publisher:

```
use myDatabase
alter table Tbl_TypeLignePaye
      alter column natureTypeLignePaye nvarchar(12)
go
```

where field `natureTypeLignePaye` was originally `nvarchar(3) null`

The query ran without errors on the main database. The result is the following:

1. The field natureTypeLignePaye still appears as `nvarchar(3)` in the object browser
2. The column properties screen indicates a `nvarchar` type with a length of `12`
3. The change was not propagated to the subscribers

Any idea on what is going on with this database?

*Publisher: object browser window vs property window give incoherent data*

[image: field type and length]

Comment: See my answer http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/45444/8783 that will help you.

Comment: Did you see my answer ?

Answer (score 4):

If anyone wants to *increase the column width of the replicated table* in SQL Server 2008, then no need to change the property of `replicate_ddl=1`. Simply follow the steps as given.

1. Open SSMS
2. Connect to Publisher database
3. run command

   ```
   ALTER TABLE [Table_Name] ALTER COLUMN [Column_Name] varchar(22)
   ```
4. It will increase the column width from varchar(x) to varchar(22) and same change you can see on subscriber (transaction got replicated). So no need to re-initialize the replication

Hope this will help all who are looking for it.

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not saying we know ***why*** this happened, but DDL instruction was properly distributed once we stopped\restarted the SQL service on the publisher ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure DDL will only come over with the new snapshot

Comment: Yes in Pub/Sub replication DDL will only come over with the new snapshot. So whenever you work at DDL you have to pulish to propagate.

Comment: sorry but adding. modifying and deleting columns and constraints do not need a new snapshot. Adding or deleting a table would require such a step.